# emberjs upload file

Tags: fileupload, ember.js

ember+rails. Есть необходимость загружать файлы на сервер. Нашел такую статью http://blog.mattbeedle.name/posts/file-uploads-in-ember-data/
Получилось вот так:

templates/posts/new.hbs:

```
<h2>post new</h2>
<form > 
    author: {{input value=model.author}}
    title: {{input value=model.title}}
    extended: {{input value=model.extended}}
    intro: {{input value=model.intro}}
    image: {{upload-file name="image" file="image"}}
    <button {{action "submit" model}} type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Create</button> 
</form>
```

templates/components/upload-file.coffee:

```
EmberRails.UploadFileComponent = Ember.TextField.extend
    tagName: 'input'
    attributeBindings: ['name']
    type: 'file'
    file: null
    change: (e) =>
        reader = new FileReader()
        reader.onload = (e) =>
            fileToUpload = e.target.result
            Ember.run =>
                Ember.set(@, 'file', fileToUpload)
                console.log(Ember.get(@,'file'))
        reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0])
```

routes/posts/new.js.coffee:

```
EmberRails.PostsNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: ->
        @store.createRecord('post')
})
```

controllers/posts.js.coffee:

```
EmberRails.PostsNewController = Ember.Controller.extend
    actions:
        submit: ->
            post = @model
            post.save().then =>
                @transitionToRoute 'post', post

EmberRails.PostsController = Ember.Controller.extend
    actions:
        destroy:(post) ->
            post.destroyRecord().then =>
                @transitionToRoute 'posts'
```

после выбора файла в консоли вижу что то типа    `data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4QvARXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABwESAAMAAAABAAEAAAEaAAUA…60UnGtfwqXq/iASu2HaSjxXoo041lzr83L/wBf+ADbKu48oTVtLXjwSjRr9vlKmv8AvTA//9k=`
при клике на это, открывается выбранный файл. Но при создании записи, поле image передается пустое

```
Processing by PostsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"post"=>{"title"=>"11", "author"=>"11", "intro"=>"11", "extended"=>"11", "image"=>nil}}
```

судя по всему, в upload-file некорректная строка

```
Ember.set(@, 'file', fileToUpload)
```

вопрос, что в данном случае @ и как записать в модель эти данные?

```
info:
Ember Inspector 1.9.5
Ember 2.3.1
Ember Data 2.3.3
jQuery 1.12.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Добрый день.

Вы бы написали свою модель данных и route соответствующий, но в целом конечно можно догадаться.

У вас есть компонент upload-file.coffee
У него срабатывает событие onChange, в результате чего свойство file компонента получает значение равное readAsDataURL файла.

В шаблоне вы пишите

```
image: {{upload-file name="image" file="image"}}
```

т.е. привязываетесь к image, хотя в других местах привязываетесь к модели.
Видимо вам надо написать

```
image: {{upload-file name="image" file=model.image}}
```